# Flash As2 save actions of the code in different scenes

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I have three scenes. In number 1 I have 2 buttons. Each button go to a different scene. In button 1 I have:

```
on (release) { 
gotoAndPlay ("scene", 1); 
button._alpha=50; 
}
```

Then I go to the scene, I read some text, I click other button to go back to the scene 1 where the buttons are, but the alpha is not applied.

How can i "save" the actions of the code in the scene 1 when i go back to it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take to this problem.  For starters, the reason this is happening is because when a Keyframe is no longer present on the timeline, it is unloaded from memory, so when you go back, it is reloaded.  This leaves us with two solutions.

1. Make each frame a movieclip and extend their timelines throughout the entire project.  This is usually done by putting each frame on its own layer, then swapping the depths.  You can do this via _root.getNextHighestDepth() to get the top layer.  Then the data on each one is never unloaded.
2. The other option is to store the alpha in a variable in a script keyframe/layer.  This one should ideally have no actual content on it, and only contain actionscript.  It must extend through the entirety of your primary timeline.  Then each display keyframe would grab the values on their respective onClipEvent(load) or on(load) events, depending on how you set up your content.